# Turning on Saxon performance analysis in eXist-db

Tags: saxon, exist-db

I've used the performance analysis tool in Saxon (https://www.saxonica.com/documentation11/index.html#!using-xsl/performanceanalysis) to analyze stylesheets, and it's quite useful.  I'd like to do the analysis from within eXist-db rather than the command line.  For one, the performance could be different.  But mainly because some stylesheets open documents in exist-db, and I can't run these from the command line.  Is there a way to configure Saxon to output the profile.html document when it's run via eXist-db?

I was hoping there would be an attribute in conf.xml , or attributes that could be sent via transform:transform(), but I don't see any options related to the performance analysis tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be certain this will work, but it's worth a try.

The `$attributes` parameter of Exist-db's `transform()` method allows you to set Saxon configuration properties. The available properties are listed at https://www.saxonica.com/documentation11/index.html#!configuration/config-features . You could try setting the properties TRACE_LISTENER_CLASS (to "net.sf.saxon.trace.TimingTraceListener") and TRACE_LISTENER_OUTPUT_FILE (to the required "profile.html" output file).

Incidentally, note that the performance is going to be different when you run with a trace listener. The profile generated using -TP is useful because it tells you which templates and functions are accounting for the most time and therefore need attention; the absolute numbers are not important or accurate. The hot spots will almost certainly be the same whether you are running within eXist or from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this did work. Here's the XQL I used:

```
let $params := 
    <parameters>
    </parameters>
let $attributes := 
    <attributes>
        <attr name="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/traceListenerClass" value="net.sf.saxon.trace.TimingTraceListener"/>
        <attr name="http://saxon.sf.net/feature/traceListenerOutputFile" value="/tmp/profile.html"/>
    </attributes>
let $serialization := 'method=html5 media-type=text/html indent=no'
return transform:transform($xml, $xsl, $params, $attributes, $serialization)
```